# Gap between <select> tag when user selecting

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a form and in that form I have multiple `<select>` tags but
when I press `Ctr + A`
I get gaps and whitespaces in the selection like this:

[image]

This happens in every browser except Firefox
I tried completely removing the whitespace and newlines from the code but it still didn't work
any idea how to fix this?

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64mf0ren/57/)

Source Code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

form {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

form label {
  margin: 2rem 1rem 1rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>

    <label><span style="color:red">* </span>Must fill</label><select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select><br>
    <hr>

    <label> generic Q :</label><br>
    <select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select><br>

    <label> another generic Q :</label><br>
    <select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select><br>
    <label>Fill Info</label><br>
    <textarea></textarea><br>

    <label>Fill other info<br>(additional)</label><br>
    <textarea></textarea><br>

    <button>Send</button>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It's because you have margin on your label

Comment: What is the use case? Browsers handle selections differently. There is not an inherent ERROR in Chrome, just a different way of handling newlines and whitespace. So what is the end result here?

Comment: @Sfili_81 I tired changing margin values and adding padding instead but neither seems to work, could you elaborate or post an answer ?

Comment: @mplungjan the end result is that i just want it to look neat when a user selects everything, it looks kinda unprofessional with gaps in between

Comment: But WHY would anyone want to select everything. Most browsers will not even ALLOW selection of form content, so a better bet is to have some "Preview" button that formats what the user entered into a nice div

Comment: @cakelover I agree with @Sfili_81, you can reposition them, using `top` and `left`

Comment: @TechyShadow could u post how so i can mark as solved?

Comment: ok sure let me post

Comment: I have posted a answer

Comment: @cakelover what is your desired output?

Comment: @Sfili_81 The same as given in the picture but without the long weird standing selection highlights at the end of the label or select or text area tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! It was stupidly simple:

```
br{
  user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe this will help**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

form {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  margin: 2rem 0rem 1rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label style="margin-right: 1rem;">
      <span style="color:red">* </span>Must fill</label>
    <select>
      <option required>option 1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <label> generic Q :</label><br>
    <select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label> another generic Q :</label><br>
    <select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label>Fill Info</label><br>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br>
    <label>Fill other info<br>(additional)</label><br>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <br>
    <button>Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Changed

```
form label {
  margin: 2rem 1rem 1rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

to

```
label {
  margin: 2rem 0rem 1rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

added `margin-right: 1rem` for the first `<label>`

I think you should reduce some more margin b/w them to remove the other spaces\gaps.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `position: absolute` along with `top` and `left` this helps you to reposition your labels however you want without making a gap.

Try this code

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

form {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: {adjust as per need};
  left: {adjust as per need};
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

form label {
  top: {adjust as per need};
  left: {adjust as per need};
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>

    <label><span style="color:red">* </span>Must fill</label><select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select><br>
    <hr>

    <label> generic Q :</label><br>
    <select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select><br>

    <label> another generic Q :</label><br>
    <select>
      <option>option 1</option>
    </select><br>
    <label>Fill Info</label><br>
    <textarea></textarea><br>

    <label>Fill other info<br>(additional)</label><br>
    <textarea></textarea><br>

    <button>Send</button>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

Visit [here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) to know more about positions

Also as per @Sfili_81 said you can also simply remove/or adjust the margin and you wont have gaps

Comment: why you use position:absolute? it's not a good solution for this case

Comment: Hmm, then what position would you suggest

Comment: position:absolute remove's element from normal flow. if you simply remove/or adjust the margin you don't have the gaps.

Comment: I am not sure about using margins and padding

Comment: I have edited my post, thanks for letting me know